# What's the 'correct' way to test Runnables that can not be directly seen by a JUnit test?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit

I have a series of tests to create, and in some of them the test in question leads to part of the work being done in a seperate thread. Because this work takes place in another thread, and it doesn't take any objects as parameters, JUnit/Mockito cannot see what is happening inside the thread. This means if the code fails in some way then JUnit can not see the thrown Exception, meaning it will assume no exceptions are thrown during the test and possibly 'pass' it when it shouldn't.

The runnable in question does not directly communicate with the thread that starts it, so at the moment I have been creating tests that simply look for outside impressions that the thread makes on other files that it works on, calls to a database, etc.

Is this a sound testing approach, are there problems with this that it sounds like I haven't considered? Should I mock out part about creating this runnable, and then test the runnable on its own? Or are there other, better paths I should take?

---

Note: I can not make any modifications to the code I am testing, unfortunately.

Comment: I know this isn't helpful but what is the point of testing the code if you can't modify it? What if you find a bug in the code? I would normally move the business logic out of the runnable and call it from the runnable. This means you can test the business logic in isolation.

Comment: The code I'm working on works, it's been tested manually, so the chances of anything not working properly at the moment are slim to none. In the future changes will be made to the code when new projects working on it start. To save time during these new projects, automated unit tests are being created now.

Comment: It depends on how your Runnable is created and run, but if all you want to do is test correctness (and not test concurrency) you use an Executor of some sort, you can pass in a "mocked" Executor to a test-only constructor that forces everything to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help more without knowing exactly what's happening in the runnables and also if you can refactor them or not.

Perhaps you could pass a listener into the runnable to make it more testable.

```
public interface Listener {
   void onSuccess(Object context);
   void onError(Object context, Throwable t);
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Listener listener;
    /// constructor;
    public void run() {
       Object context = ...;
       try {
          doStuff(context);
          listener.onSuccess(context);
       } catch (Throwable t) {
          listener.onError(context, t);
       }
    }
}
```

If you can't refactor the runnable, the only things you can test for are outside effects. If this is a unit test and you have implemented IOC, you could mock the service dependencies and test for service invocations (eg using Mockito).

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot refactor them, I'll update my question about this now. So you would suggest that just testing the outside observable effects is the best approach, and not to bother stubbing out its creation and then testing the runnable on its own where JUnit/Mockito can see it?